# Can HTML table cells be rearranged with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wonder if it is possible to rearrange HTML table cells using only CSS.

For example can this

```
------------------------------------------------
|             A            |    B    |    C    |
------------------------------------------------
```

be displayed as:

```
------------------------------------------------
|    C    |             A            |    B    |
------------------------------------------------
```

or perhaps even this:

```
-------------------------
|           A           |
-------------------------
|     B     |     C     |
-------------------------
```

Is this possible with CSS only or is it necessary to modify the HTML nodes?

**EDIT:** Some of you were wondering why this is needed at all, so here's the real-life problem I'm facing:

I want to display a list of issues reported by users:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Problem description (A) | Reporting user (B) | Link to affected entity (C) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wanted to evaluate various layouts. The first layout variant would emphasize the reporting user, the second one would emphasize the text description.

I don't have any problem in changing the structure, and in fact I already did, but as I was coding this, I wondered if it is possible to do with CSS. (Just pure curiosity)

Comment: Is something that only works in modern browsers acceptable?

Comment: Are you specifically referring to table cells, as in using `<table>` elements, or are you talking about a table-less, table-like design? What you're asking for is really not too difficult in a table-less design.

Comment: Why are you doing this with CSS? If you want to change the meaning/structure of the table, change the HTML.

Comment: @thirtydot: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: @Wex: Classic HTML `<table> <tr> <td>`.

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't want to change the meaning, I'd just like to change the layout.

Comment: well, for a table, the layout tends to communicate meaning.

Comment: @DR: I was thinking of Flexbox, it's already been suggested. It can definitely do the first example, not sure about the second.

Comment: @DA: true, but so do most visual representions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but it's not the best thing to do though (see other answers).
Here's my example:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0}
.type-a .b {width: 50%; float:left;}
.type-a .a {width:100%; float:left;}
.type-a .c {width: 50%; float:left;}

.type-b .b {width: 25%; float:left;}
.type-b .a {width: 50%; float:right;}
.type-b .c {width: 25%; float:left;}
```

```html
<table class="type-a" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="a" style="background-color:#060">A</td>
    <td class="b" style="background-color:#006">B</td>
    <td class="c" style="background-color:#600">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a" style="background-color:#060">A</td>
    <td class="b" style="background-color:#006">B</td>
    <td class="c" style="background-color:#600">C</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
<br />
<table class="type-b" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="a" style="background-color:#060">A</td>
    <td class="b" style="background-color:#006">B</td>
    <td class="c" style="background-color:#600">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="a" style="background-color:#060">A</td>
    <td class="b" style="background-color:#006">B</td>
    <td class="c" style="background-color:#600">C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ye8Qa/)

Comment: Technically when you define `float: left | right;` for elements that are `display:table-cell` you are removing them from the table layout management completely. For example if you want to make cells in the row to be of the same height your approach will not work.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ye8Qa/1/

Comment: @c-smile, 100% correct. I did state that this is not the best thing to do and your comment is another reason why. The question also didn't state it had to adhere to table layout management - although it was probably implied ;)

Comment: MY EYES!!!! this has to be the worst color selection

Answer (score 3):

Over a decade later, we can hack a solution together using modern CSS.

At first I thought about using [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), but I think that's not appropriate to this case. Instead, I'm going to hack this table by using nested [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Let's first look at the DOM tree of a table:

```
table
  ├ thead (optional)
  │ ⋮
  ├ tfoot (optional)
  │ ⋮
  └ tbody (one or many)
    ├ tr
    │ ├ td/th
    │ ⋮
    │ └ td/th
    ⋮
    └ tr
      ├ td/th
      ⋮
      └ td/th
```

The structure inside `thead` and `tfoot` is the same as `tbody`.

We will replace the table layout with a 3-level-nested flexbox layout:

- A `table` element that will have a vertical (i.e. column) flexbox. This will have usually one child (just the `tbody`), but sometimes two or three children (`thead` and `tfoot` in addition to `tbody`), or even more children (multiple consecutive `tbody` elements are allowed).

  - Table section elements that will have a vertical (i.e. column) flexbox. The children are the table rows.

    - Table row elements that will have a horizontal (i.e. row) flexbox.
    - For bonus points, we can let this layout [wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).

      - Table cells that can be reordered using [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) and resized using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (which is a shorthand for [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink), [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)).
      - Automatic column width will be impossible, all columns must have their width known in advance.

Look at this code (and run the snippet to see the results).

```css
table.flextable {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 4px;
}
table.flextable > thead,
table.flextable > tfoot,
table.flextable > tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1px;
}
table.flextable > * > tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1px;
}

/* Column A has twice the width. Column C comes before the other two. */
table.flextable.type-a .a {flex: 2 2 0; order: 1;}
table.flextable.type-a .b {flex: 1 1 0; order: 1;}
table.flextable.type-a .c {flex: 1 1 0; order: 0;}

/* These dimensions cannot add up to 100% due to gap/margin/padding/border. */
/* Thus, we are using calc() to disregard that extra space. */
table.flextable.type-b .a {flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 1px - 2em);}
table.flextable.type-b .b {flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 1px - 2em);}
table.flextable.type-b .c {flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 1px - 2em);}

/* Stylistic rules, not relevant to the layout. */
.a {background-color: #CFC;}
.b {background-color: #CCF;}
.c {background-color: #FCC;}
td, th {padding: 0.5em 1em;}
td::before {content: "<td>";}
th::before {content: "<th>";}
td::after {content: "</td>";}
th::after {content: "</th>";}
```

```html
<h2>Plain table</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="a">A</th> <th class="b">B</th> <th class="c">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">a</td> <td class="b">b</td> <td class="c">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">a</td> <td class="b">b</td> <td class="c">c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Reordering the table cells</h2>

<table class="flextable type-a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="a">A</th> <th class="b">B</th> <th class="c">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">a</td> <td class="b">b</td> <td class="c">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">a</td> <td class="b">b</td> <td class="c">c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Wrapping one table row into two rows</h2>

<table class="flextable type-b">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="a">A</th> <th class="b">B</th> <th class="c">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">a</td> <td class="b">b</td> <td class="c">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="a">a</td> <td class="b">b</td> <td class="c">c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This answer is kept short for the educational value. The following issues are left as an exercise to the reader:

- `tfoot` should come before `tbody`, but browsers should display it after all `tbody` elements. This can be hacked in this flexbox by using the `order` property.
- Cells that have a `colspan` will pose some challenges, but they can probably be worked around by adding a few more CSS rules.
- Cells that have a `rowspan` will certainly break the layout. It will be very difficult to fix it without additional changes to the HTML.
- [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) is not supported in this hack, because we are not using the [CSS table model](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css2/#table-display).
- `<caption>` is not implemented in this code, but can likely be supported easily.
- `<colgroup>`, `<col>` elements are not supported here.
- We can avoid adding a class to each table cell by clever usage of [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Answer (score 2):

No such feature at the moment in CSS.

CSS3 will offer [flexbox model](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/) in one form or another (work on it is in active development at the moment at W3C). It should allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a dirty way, you could always try to use the float feature.

but for the last design that you provided as an example, I think you should be able to play around with the width (top one should be width:100%; and the other 2 should be 50%)

Answer (score 0):

you can do all three, with proper markup, although added, and a touch of css. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/xvBhF/

fair warning: i'm not sure how well at's can handle manipulating table data like this, i want to just say they don't, but regardless, if you're going public then you probably want to look into that. i'm sure there's a way with all the html attribute flavors that only come in table style.