# How to rearrange table td

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this problem, is there a way to change the order of the td and th with "testing" class such that it will be the first column on mobile but moves to the last column on desktop? thanks.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col" class="testing">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td class="testing">@mdo</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td class="testing">@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can HTML table cells be rearranged with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373177/can-html-table-cells-be-rearranged-with-css) or this [Why Won't HTML Table Rows Sort Using Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906506/why-wont-html-table-rows-sort-using-flexbox)

Comment: You could probably do this with a flexbox layout and the order property. You could also have one hide/show when you have certain screen sizes. Like two different elements available. You could also use some js which fires when the screen changes sizes and reorders the html.

Comment: Hi winner_Joiner and async await thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using flex and the css order property. I used the hover property because it's easier to test than resizing the snippet, but you could change the style from a hover to a media query and check the screen size.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.6rem;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

td:nth-child(0) {
  order: 0;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  order: 4;
}

td:nth-child(5) {
  order: 5;
}

.fl {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.lf {
  background-color: pink;
}

table:hover .fl {
  order: 5;
}

table:hover .lf {
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fl">first no-hover, last hover</td>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>fourth</td>
    <td class="lf">first hover, last no-hover</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```